# Kinect V2 Skeleton Tracking

Tags: ros, kinect, iai-kinect2, skeletal-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm currently working on a project that involves Kinect v2 for Windows. I've successfully installed OpenKinect2 driver as well as iai_kinect2 ROS package. I'm able to see RGB, etc information coming out from kinect2_bridge. However, my end goal is to detect human with skeleton tracking algorithm. Does anyone know any library that can accomplish this? All the ROS libraries I've seen are only compatible with the older version of Kinect.

I'm using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 and the sensor is the kinect V2 for Windows.

Thanks,

Jim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218472/kinect-v2-skeleton-tracking/) by [renxinhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24156/renxinhe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-09-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on 2016-05-12**:
Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Haven't tried it yet but there is this one: https://github.com/mcgi5sr2/kinect2_tracker

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0